# Can a Liferay V6.0.6 be written using Maven build system?

Tags: java, maven, liferay

Liferay uses Ant SDK up to Version 6.0.6.
Since Version 6.1+ it now supports Maven.

I would like to know if I can build any plugin using Maven.
By the way, the maven support is only for V6.1+, what I am trying to infer here is a way to do it using Maven for V6.0.6 line.

Comment: As neither 6.0 CE nor 6.1 CE are no longer supported, e.g. won't get any more updates, my suggestion is to upgrade to 6.2 and use maven there. Alternatively update to EE which is still supported but AFAIK also doesn't have official maven support.

Comment: Thanks @OlafKock. Yes I know that is a path to go, but suppose I have a site with V6.06 which cannot be migrated, thus I am stuck to Ant SDK and not Maven SDK which way best(but Gradle is better). Thus this is almost leading me to give up. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems there is not alternative. Thus I will have to resort to Ant when building plugins for Liferay prior to V6.1, and Ant/Maven afterwards, i.e., V6.1+ can be programmed using ant or maven build systems or Gradle (proviede there is such script upon this technology).

I, then, will use Maven.

Thanks for participatin in my searh in this topic.